# Principal value of a double integral numerically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex

I have several integrals of the form :

[image]

where [image] and [image] .

where a,b,wc and T are constants
and PV denotes the Cauchy principal value I tried to integrate one of this  form using NIntegrate however when trying to compute the principal value.  I tried:

```
HLS[nu_, phi_, t_] := 
 t^2 (Sinc[(omega - phi)*t/2]^2)*(alpha*
 Exp[-nu/wc]*
 nu)*( (1/(Exp[nu/T] - 1)) /(phi + nu))

NIntegrate[
HLS[nu, phi, 5], {nu, -Infinity, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Infinity}, 
Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

But I get NIntegrate::pvdim: PrincipalValue can be used for one-dimensional integrals only.

The principal value should make the integral convergent, I have spent a few days on it by now. I don't usually use mathematica but python and there the function is also only supported for one dimensional integrals so I gather this is a difficult problem. However I'd appreciate any advice or work arounds.

Comment: The integral under consideration is not any principal value, but  an iterated integral, where the inner integral is taken as  its ptrincipal value.

Comment: Perhaps I did not phrase it correctly still, the principal value needs to be taken in the inner integral, do you have any clue as to how to code it ?

Comment: Evaluate parameters, e.g. `t = 1; omega = 4; phi = 5; alpha = 2; wc = 1; T = 2;`. Unfortunately, then `Integrate[
 t^2 (Sinc[(omega - phi)*t/2]^2)*(alpha*Exp[-nu/wc]*
    nu)*((1/(Exp[nu/T] - 1))/(phi + nu)), {nu, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]` produces an error "Integrate::idiv: Integral of (2 E^-nu nu Sinc[1/2]^2)/((-1+E^(nu/2)) (5+nu)) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.".

Comment: The integration limits of your Mathematica code don't match the given formula. Please check if the integration is over $[0,+\infty)$ or over $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: I get a problem about nonnumerical values, since the parameters are undefined. Without their values, it's discouraging even to investigate further...consider posting them.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compute it numerically for a specific set of constants then you could possibly create a table of principal-values of the inner integral over a range of $\phi$.  Note in the code below I specify the two singular points of 0 and $\phi$ in the integration limits as {0,s1,s2,infty} then run the inner integration as principal-value as $\phi$ ranges from 0.1 to 15 and note the sum does appear to be converging for at least $\phi\geq 0.1$ for delta phi=1/4.  Not sure what it would look like if you start decreasing delta phi to 1/100 or 1/1000.   However your notation was a bit unclear.  Perhaps you can further develop the code below to your liking.

**Update:**  I think to integrate it this way, would have to multiply the value of each inner principal-value integral by delta phi like a Riemann sum which I did not do in the code below.

```
(*
 Let a=1, t=1, b=1, w_c=1, T=2
*)
myf2[v_, \[Phi]_] := (v Exp[-v])/((Exp[v/2] - 1) (\[Phi] - v))
sum = 0;
myDoubleSum = Table[
   sum += 
    NIntegrate[
     Sinc[1 + thePhi]^2 myf2[v, thePhi], {v, 0, 0, 
      thePhi, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"];
   {thePhi, sum},
   {thePhi, 0.1, 15, 1/4}];
ListPlot[myDoubleSum, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and get back to you if I have any doubts. Sorry about the notation I mainly wanted to see a way to do it, summing over the second integral seems like a great way I did not think about it, it looks like what I expected!

Comment: Not quite sure about the legitimacy of doing that.   Something you can work on perhaps.